# How to determine if a loop using "task" is parallelized?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm totally new to openmp and learning how to parallelized loops using `task`. I made the following loop:

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none) firstprivate(left) private(i) shared(length, pivot, data)
    {
#pragma omp for
        for(i = 1; i<length-1; i++)
        {
#pragma omp task
            {
                if(data[left] > pivot)
                {
                    i = length;
                }
                else
                {
                    left = i;
                }
            }
        }
#pragma omp taskwait
    }
```

I'm not sure if it's parallelized properly as it's taking more time than it's supposed to. How can I improve my code?

Comment: The loop body compiles into ~10 machine instructions. Creating, queueing, and executing an OpenMP task costs orders of magnitude more. Can you spot the problem now?

Comment: @HristoIliev So, what's your advice? Is this code parallelizable at all?

Comment: In this case, you should use `#pragma omp parallel for` anyway, since this pragma is designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the task directive is totally irrelevant since (#pragma omp for) do the job.

Task is used for unbounded loops.